# Formatting date to unix timestamp in milliseconds with Moment.js returns format string

Tags: javascript, unix, momentjs

I'm aware there are lots of questions here asking similar, but having looked through the answers I seem to be getting unexpected results.

I have a full date and I need to convert it to a unix timestamp in **milliseconds**

The date is in full format: `Tue Dec 06 2016 10:51:47 GMT+0000 (GMT)`

If I try to format it using the `x` identifier for unix milliseconds (shown in the documentation) I literally just get the string `"x"` back

`moment(date).format('x') // = x`

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to convert `date` into something other than the full format before I do this? Why does passing the argument to `format()` just return me back the format I typed in there?

Comment: You could always do `moment(date).toDate().getTime()`

Comment: @adeneo thanks! That does actually work, but I'd still like to find out where I was going wrong with the above.

Comment: Are you using version 2.8.4 or above, the `x` option was added then

Comment: Just tested it, and any version below 2.8.4 will indeed just return the `x`

Comment: @adeneo you are correct, my version is outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` option was added in Moment 2.8.4, any version older than that will just return the letter `x` rather than the unix time in milliseconds.

Version 2.8.4

```js
var date = 'Tue Dec 06 2016 10:51:47 GMT+0000 (GMT)';
var unix = moment(new Date(date)).format('x');
console.log(unix);
```

```html
<p>Version 2.8.4 - working !</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And an older version

```js
var date = 'Tue Dec 06 2016 10:51:47 GMT+0000 (GMT)';
var unix = moment(new Date(date)).format('x');
console.log(unix);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the newer versions of Moment also deprecates construction from random strings, so

```
moment("Tue Dec 06 2016 10:51:47 GMT+0000 (GMT)")
```

Will give you a deprecation notice, see -> https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Comment: The preferred solution to the deprecation warning is to provide a format parameter, not to use the `Date` object constructor.

Comment: @MattJohnson - no, the preferred solution is to pass in a valid ISO string, but to just get around the issue for this answer I used the native Date constructor to parse the date instead, which is also not a very good idea, as implementations can differ, and the only valid format for the Date constructor should also be a ISO string or multiple arguments.